# Get Access Token - Design Automation for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have created the app, was able to debug the source code.

Also received Client ID and Client secret.

I need your help to understand how to get access token.

Basically this part -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdtpZ.png)

It will be really helpful if you can provide a sample code on how to send the HTTP request as I am novice to web API's.

I have added this code to my solution -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7WwP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKhUF.png)

Thanks,
STR

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, how to obtain an Access token.
You need to add NewtonSoft.Json nuget package to your project to run it.

```
public class TokenModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        credentials.Add("client_id", "YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
        credentials.Add("client_secret", "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET");
        credentials.Add("grant_type", "YOUR_GRANT_TYPE");
        credentials.Add("scope", "YOUR_SCOPE");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(credentials);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/authentication/v1/authenticate", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(responseData).AccessToken;
            }
        }
    }
```

And simple usage:

```
var token=await GetToken();
```

It is not perfect, I've tried to simplify all the moments.